# Parse HTML text not in a tag using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to get some text that isn't enclosed by any HTML elements except for in the body tag, but the problem is that the text is broken up by other tags and needs to go into separate cells.

For example:

```
<a id="00:00:00" class="ts">[00:00:00]</a> <font class="mn">Name1</font> First bit of text<br/>
<a id="00:00:09" class="ts">[00:00:09]</a> <font class="mn">Name2</font> Second Line of Text<br/>
<a id="00:01:17" class="ts">[00:01:17]</a> <font class="mn">Name3</font> A third line of text<br/>
<a id="00:01:59" class="ts">[00:01:59]</a> <font class="mn">Name4</font> The final line of text<br/>
```

I am able to get the timestamps as well as the names into their respective columns, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get each line of text into the corresponding rows.

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Timestamp As Object
Dim Name As Object

my_url = "path_to_url.html"
Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
xml_obj.send
html_doc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
Set xml_obj = Nothing

Set Timestamp = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("a")
Set Name = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("font")

i = 2
For Each itm In Timestamp
    If itm.getAttribute("className") = "ts" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = itm.innerText
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

i = 2
For Each itm In Name
    If itm.getAttribute("className") = "mn" Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = itm.innerText
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

I was thinking about maybe using `<br/>` in some way and using LEFT, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the content you show the only content there is in the response?

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim. Using your code I was able to add in comments that were one line. However, I did run into an unexpected problem: The HTML is used as an online chat log, so while most entries are handled ok, I found a few instances where the text attributed to somebody read as "I copied something <br></br>into the chat box <br></br> and the chat log kept all the newline." This is making it so your code creates three separate rows instead of one, attributing "into the chat box" to another user, and so on. I'm looking into some sort of error catch right now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. It did affect the formatting of the cells a bit because now there is an extra blank newline attached to each of the comment cells, doubling the cell height, but they are lining up great over the 200+ lines. If you could maybe help with the formatting, or if that's a result of the custom splitter that you used that needs to stay. Either way thanks and I'll mark as answered.

Comment: See update - you might have to tweak that a bit

Comment: Worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as that's the only content in the response and there are no other sections you could do something like this:

**EDIT:** revised to split on something other than

```
Sub Tester()

    Const RW_START As Long = 5
    Const SPLITTER = "{xxxx}"
    Dim i As Integer, html_doc, itm
    Dim Timestamp As Object
    Dim Name As Object
    Dim arr, sep, txt

    Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html_doc.body.innerHTML = Range("A1").Value 'for my testing...


    Set Timestamp = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set Name = html_doc.body.getElementsByTagName("font")

    i = RW_START
    For Each itm In Timestamp
        If itm.getAttribute("className") = "ts" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = itm.innerText
            itm.innerText = "" '<<<
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    i = RW_START
    For Each itm In Name
        If itm.getAttribute("className") = "mn" Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = itm.innerText
            itm.innerText = IIf(i = RW_START, "", SPLITTER) '<<<
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    'get the remaining text and split on newline (<br>)
    arr = Split(html_doc.body.innerText, SPLITTER)
    i = RW_START
    For Each itm In arr
        itm = Trim(itm) 
        'remove trailing vbLf
        If Right(itm, 1) = vblf Then itm = Left(itm, Len(itm)-1)
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Trim(itm)
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```